# Data not showing, but items are stored

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

[image: I have added 5 items in thsi datatable]

Good day, I'm having a visual problem to my NGX-datatable, The items are being added and deducted as you can see on the image above, I have 5 total items, but none are showing. I'm updating the value of this table realtime with a modal that sends an @Output to the list, even the key's are matching.

here is my code:
for the HTML:

```
<ngx-datatable
style="height: 500px"
class="material fullscreen"
[columnMode]="'force'"
[headerHeight]="50"
[footerHeight]="50"
[rowHeight]="50"
[scrollbarV]="true"
[scrollbarH]="true"
[rows]="filteredItems">

<ngx-datatable-column name="id" [width]="100">
<ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template>
    ID
</ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>

<-- My Modal -->
<app-modal-child
(newItemEvent) = "newItemEvent($event)"
></app-modal-child>
```

for the TS Parent that handles the event:

```
newItemEvent(value: any) {
    this.filteredItems = value;
}
```

for the Modal TS that triggers the event:

```
@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

onNewItemUpdate(value: any) {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(value);
}

onSelect({ selected }) {
    this.itemData.splice(0, this.itemData.length);
    this.itemData.push(...selected)
    this.onNewItemUpdate(this.itemData);
}
```

Comment: It should be `[rows]="filteredItems"` instead of `rows]="filteredItems"` I think

Comment: Additionally, it seems that your passing the same reference to your parent component. If your parent is using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, try telling angular to detect changes manually using `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `detectChanges()` method

Comment: @MikeS.I tried your suggestion still doesn't appear, also the rows was just a typo on my part. It works here on my machine

Comment: @MikeS.Actually I'm not familiar on your suggestion, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: It would be easier if you could reproduce the problem over at https://www.stackblitz.com. Alternatively there's more info about change detection [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)